# Serial Communication between MATLAB and STM running Micropython

Tags: python, matlab, serial-port, stm32, micropython

Was hoping I could get some pointers on how to setup communications between MATLAB and an STM32L476 Nucleo-64.

The idea behind this is to essentially navigate some pre generated terrain, using the MATLAB script to create the map of the terrain and show position, while the STM sends in the control action to act as an 'onboard' processor for a robot navigating the path.

The MATLAB script is set up to generate 3 numbers (1 d.p.), corresponding to sensor measurements, which is then sent to the STM via serial communication, the STM will then calculate the control action, which should correspond to two integers returned.
This setup does work using an Arduino as this is what was used previously (so I know there is no issues with MATLAB generating the sensor measurements or terrain), however I need to change the hardware over to STM running micropython, which is where I am running into the trouble.

Am hoping that someone may be able to point me in the right direction, I have used the serial command in MATLAB to write to the board:

```
s = serial('COM3','BaudRate',115200,'timeout',1);
fopen(s);
.....
fprintf(s,y(1));
fprintf(s,y(2));
fprintf(s,y(3));
```

Where y is the sensor measurements. I was then was hoping to read the response from the STM back in using `fread(s)` - this does give numbers for each iteration, however they are quite often repeated and are no where close to what was set on the STM (it also returns a 14x1 array when it should only be a 2x1). I think my mistake maybe in the STM side of things as I tried to read the data in by setting up another serial port.

```
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM3',
    baudrate=115200)

dat = []

while True:
    # Collect sensor data
    yLeft = (dat[1])
    yRight = (dat[2])
    yFront = (dat[3])
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated - I just seem to be going around in circles at the moment.

Edit - At the moment to try and get it to work I am trying to get it to react to one number and print the result to MATLAB

```
import serial
import time
import sys

# Declare states
state_list = ['WAIT', 'TEN']
state = 'WAIT'  # Default state on init is wait

# Initialise variables
V = 0

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM3',
    baudrate=115200)

while True:

    ser.open()
    V = ser.read()
    ser.close()

    # Make decisions according to state machine
    if state == 'WAIT':
        print('WAITING')
        if V > 10:
            state = 'TEN'
        else:
            state = state

    elif state == 'TEN':
        print('TEN')
        if V < 10:
            state = 'WAIT'
        else:
            state = state

    else:
         print('END OF PROGRAM')
```

Then the corresponding MATLAB script is:

```
%% clean up
clear all
clc
%% Set up serial
sobj = 'COM3';

s = serial(sobj,'BaudRate',115200,'timeout',1);
fopen(s);

%% Run Simulation

% Create Data Array to be sent to STM
DatatoSend=15;

% Print data to STM
fprintf(s,DatatoSend)

% Read Response from STM
data = [];
% Receive response data
data = fread(s);

fclose(s)
```

I am not confident that I am even close to getting this working though.

Comment: When you say the STM sends 'numbers', what are those? How many bytes is such number and are you sure Matlab expects the same?

Comment: Hi - numbers would mean any number from 0 to 1500 being sent from MATLAB to the STM, and anywhere from -255 to 255 being sent from the STM to be read by MATLAB

Comment: Sorry I meant the type. Are those integers? Floating point numbers? E.g. Matlab expects 64bit floating point, the STM might not use that. And how do you send the numbers, do they get converted into a `bytearray` or similar?

Comment: Ah sorry - they should be floating point numbers

I am attempting to send them using fprintf(s) to print them to the serial, but this is most likely part of the problem, I'm not sure how to convert into a byte array etc.

Comment: Don't have an STM to test, but to mimimize friction with converting bytes/endianess etc, you might want to try an approach where you first create a JSON string then send that, and convert it back to numbers in Matlab. Pretty sure I've seen examples on https://forum.micropython.org

Comment: I will have a look through that forum - thank you for the help :)

Comment: Can you show the MicroPython code?

Comment: Yep I can edit the post to show what I have at the moment - I don't think its very correct though